# Node-Red get msg sender

Tags: node-red

is it posible to detect the last sendernode of a msg-Object in a input-event?

```
RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
var node = this;
node.on('input', function(msg, a,b,c) {

    var sender = msg.sender ??????



    node.send(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this would go against the intention of flow based programming.

Nodes should not care what nodes come before or after them in the flow.

All state should be carried on the `msg` object

The only exception to this is for pairs of nodes that provide receive/respond functionality e.g. `http-in`/`http-response` and this is achieved by the `http-in` node adding a field to the `msg` to hold the http request/response objects

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer.
I'm looking for a node which can be used as simple "AND"-Element (like a BPMN parallel gateway). The solution must be as simple as possible.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question you asked

Comment: It's correct. I've ask about the sender of a msg object. To create a "and" node you need this information.
I would like to create a node with the "and" function. To do this, I must know all incoming path and the sender of a msg object. I have extract the information about all incoming paths from the flow definition. Now I need the sender of an incoming msg object.

Comment: You can not get this information, the best you can do is use the topic to distinguish between incoming messages. There are multiple binary logic nodes already available